# invalid json response body / Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, post, request

I have an api for discord that post the bot's guild_count. It was working before,but when I try again now it sends an error
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4a8s.png)

here is the code at user side using node-fetch:

```
      const body = { count: client.guilds.size };
fetch(`https://cloudlist.xyz/api/stats/${client.user.id}`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
    Authorization: "api_token",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(async response => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

And here is the server side post api:

```
app.post("/api/stats/:id", limiter ,async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params)
  let botId = req.params.id;
  let auth = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!auth)
    return res.json({
      success: "false",
      error: "Authorization header not found."
    });
  let count = req.body.count ? req.body.count : req.body.server_count;
  if (!count)
    return res.json({ success: "false", error: "Count not found in body." });
  count = parseInt(count);
  if (!count)
    return res.json({ success: "false", error: "Count not integer." });
  const bot = await client.fetchUser(`${botId}`);
  if (!bot) return res.json({ success: "false", error: "Bot not found." });
  // if (!bot.auth) return res.json({ "success": "false", "error": "Create a bot authorization token." });
  //if (bot.auth !== auth) return res.json({ "success": "false", "error": "Incorrect authorization token." });
  if (bot) {
    database.ref(`Bots/${botId}`).once("value", async function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.val() === null)
        return res.json({ success: "false", error: "Bot not found." });
      if (snapshot.val().apiKey != auth) {
        return res.json({
          success: "false",
          error: "Incorrect authorization token."
        });
      } else {
        database
          .ref(`Bots/${botId}`)
          .update({
            guilds_count: `${count}`
          })      
            res.json({bot: count });    
      }
    });
  }
});
```

BTW I am using body-parser on both to make sure I get the json response

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The error suggests that the server is probably sending HTML back instead of JSON. What does your browser's developer tools' Network tab say about the response? What is it sending? Also, what is `limiter`? Please share the code for that as well.

Comment: limiter is a rate limiter api. I don't think that the server is sending a HTML object,cause We are getting this object from the database and sending to the user. 
And on the tab of my server, on which the express is hosting, there is no print of anything, I can't much receive that console.log (req.params) will q be the error on the client side?

Comment: Ah, my bad. At the user side, replace `res => res.json()` with `res => res.text()` to see what the response is without trying to parse it as JSON. The `limiter` middleware is relevant because there's nothing in the server code that I see that could cause this, so the issue may be there.

Comment: Also, is there anything between the server and the client? A reverse proxy like nginx or apache? Is there any other middleware on the server that's applied to this route or the app?

Comment: I think I fixed it, turned off the cloudflare underatack and went back to work, but I find it strange, because many sites use this cloudflare verification and can use this api system

Comment: Doesn't the under attack mode display a HTML interstitial that instructs the user to wait for a few seconds? That's probably the HTML that you're being served. You might not want it for a JSON API unless they have a JSON mode. You might want to take a look at [Using Cloudflare with your API](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200504045-Using-Cloudflare-with-your-API).

Comment: Hm I will see that,thank you